# UART does not work properly after changing HSI to MSI in STM32L152

Tags: stm32, uart, low-power, clock-speed

I am using STM32L152R8T6-A MCU. I use 3 UARTs in my project. UART buadrates are 9600 and 115200 bps.

Initially I set the clock source to HSI (16MHz) and everything worked fine. But then I decided to change the clock source to MSI (2.097 or 4.194 MHz). The program runs properly but it seems that UARTs miss some bytes, i.e. instead of getting 11 bytes, it gets the last 8 bytes.

I used the STM32CubeMX configurations and didn't change anything in initializations:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_RTC;
  PeriphClkInit.RTCClockSelection = RCC_RTCCLKSOURCE_LSI;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: What supply voltage and temperature the STM32 runs at, and do either voltage or temperature change when it is running?

Comment: @Justme Everything is the same for HSI and MSI. Supply is regulated 3.3V and temperature is normal.

Comment: How are you reading from the port?

Comment: @ChrisStratton With a very simple polling mode. No interrupt is used.

Comment: What else are you doing?  Show the code

Comment: Aha, polling. If your code does things for too long (too slow clock), it can't receive the first bytes during those other things.

Comment: I'm with Chris on this one, we need to the see whole code. It would just be blindly guessing until we can examine the actual operations. Could you also provide a snapshot of the UART DR as well ? when the MCU has been running.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I investigated the problem. Low clock frequency makes UART functioning abnormally. MSI or HSI is not the case, since HSI with 4Mhz clock does not work either. More discussions here: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000SbLOgSAN/uart-does-not-work-properly-after-changing-hsi-to-msi-in-stm32l152

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that the intenal oscillator has just too much tolerance. They are factory calibrated at 3.0V and 25 °C, and HSI should be within 1% anf MSI should be within 0.5%.

So if you have not calibrated them to be accurate in your operating conditions, they could be out of required tolerance for UART comms.

Basically, for anything that requires good frequency precision, like UART comms, an external crystal should be used.

There is some possibility that since slower clock causes missing bytes, that it might have simply related to how your code runs at slower clock and cannot receive all bytes.

Comment: That's really rather unlikely to be the issue

Comment: I see internal oscillators fail to do uart properly often....it does depend on how hard you are pushing it, can drop down to a slower baud rate and get better results.